# Spaces filled when value is null

Tags: cobol

I am doing a flat file writing on cobol.
but when the variable is null , it will not fill with spaces. Please help.

Here is some of the part of flat file structure declaration.

```
01 Fs-IL494-REC.
   03 FX-IL494-TRXN-1-10                     PIC X(410) VALUE SPACES.

01 Wx-TRXN-INFO-BUF                PIC X(410) VALUE SPACES.
01 Ws-TRXN-INFO REDEFINES Wx-TRXN-INFO-BUF OCCURS 10 TIMES.
03 Wx-TRXN-DT                   PIC X(8).
03 Wx-TRXN-CDE                  PIC X(3).
03 W9-TRXN-AMT                  PIC S9(13)V9(2)
                                    SIGN LEADING SEPARATE.
03 Wx-TRXN-DESC                 PIC X(14).

Doing some query to retrive the records from database.

INITIALIZE Wx-TRXN-INFO-BUF.
INITIALIZE FX-IL494-TRXN-1-10.

ADD 1 TO W9-ARR-CNT
MOVE F9-IRC-TXN-DT TO Wx-TRXN-DT(W9-ARR-CNT)
MOVE F9-IRC-TXN-CDE TO Wx-TRXN-CDE(W9-ARR-CNT)
MOVE F9-IRC-TXN-AMT TO W9-TRXN-AMT(W9-ARR-CNT)
MOVE FX-IRC-TXN-DESC TO Wx-TRXN-DESC(W9-ARR-CNT)

MOVE Wx-TRXN-INFO-BUF TO FX-IL494-TRXN-1-10
```

Comment: Nothing looks out of order here.  I generally don't use INITIALIZE, but I doubt that's the cause of your trouble.  Which variable are we talking about?

Comment: Please fill in your query - the SELECT statement, etc. This should verify NealB's answer below.

Comment: @DavidGorsline - I was wondering why you do not generally use INITIALIZE?

Comment: @Buggabill: Joe Zitzelberger's answer captures my thoughts.  In most of the shops I worked, it was generally part of the folklore that if an old, buggy compiler were to do something unpleasant, it would have something to do with INITIALIZE.

Comment: @DavidGorsline - I would agree with that partially, but the problem that you end up with is that you might end up having spaces or some other value in numeric fields which can be ugly as well.  I guess the brevity and "magic" of the verb entices me... :-)

Answer (score 3):

My assumptions:

- This is SQL (DB/2 probably)
- You are doing a `SELECT INTO :host-variable`
- The `host-variable` is the thing you expect to be set to `SPACES` when the corresponding database table column contains a `NULL` value.

If the above is correct, the problem is that when a `NULL` value is selected off of the database, the corresponding `host-variable` is not updated. It will retain whatever value it had before the query was executed.

You may need to add a `null value indicator` to your query. When the null value indicator is set to a value less than zero (often -1) the corresponding host-variable is unchanged. This is the pattern you should be using:

```
EXEC SQL
   SELECT column-name-1,
          column-name-2
   INTO :host-var-1 :null-ind-1,
        :host-var-2 :null-ind-2
   FROM some-table
   WHERE bla bla bla...
END-EXEC
```

The "extra" variables `null-ind-1` and `null-ind-2` should be declared as `S9(4) USAGE COMP`. Notice that comma is "missing" between the host variable and the null indicator. The null indicator variables will be assigned a value less than zero when the corresponding `column-name-1` or `column-name-2` contain NULL values. Should that be the case, then `host-var-1` and `host-var-2` will remain unchanged (i.e. retain whatever values they had before the `EXEC SQL`.

In your code after the `EXEC SQL` you should be doing something like:

```
IF null-ind-1 < ZERO
   MOVE SPACES TO host-var-1
END-IF
IF null-ind-2 < ZERO
   MOVE SPACES to host-var-2
END-IF
```

I have also seen programmers simply initialize all host variables before doing the `EXEC SQL` to whatever they would want in event of a NULL column value and not bother with null indicators on the query (not hard to figure out why that would work once you know that DB2 will not update the host variable in event of a NULL value)..

Answer (score 0):

Initialize is tied to the value clause, and it's behavior can be quirky and annoying.

Far better to simple "Move spaces to my-record" before you do your read...

Comment: How do you feel that INITIALIZE is "tied to the value clause"? Do you have examples of it being "quirky"? Yes, if required at all, in this example MOVE SPACE is better.